# How would I remove duplicated words from a text file in python

Tags: python, duplicates, txt

I have some words in one line in WordsHangman.txt:

**tiger apple time watch alien pen lion *alien* *tiger* *apple***

How could I remove the duplicates , but also saving the formule-

> A word , then **SPACE** , then again a word , **SPACE** , word ...

Please answer how to replace the correct text with the one in the txt file

Comment: you would like the first instance to be preserved right?

Comment: `but also saving the formule-` I didnt understand this portion.

Comment: Split the input and use that to create a set. Then you can " ".join(...) that set.

Comment: @AlbinPaul I think they're trying to explain that they want to not have spaces doubled up once a word is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the set. First you have to create a set to eliminate duplicates and then you can join those words to get the output like below.

```
words = "tiger apple time watch alien pen lion alien tiger apple"
unique_words = set(words.split())
output = ' '.join(unique_words)
print(output)
```

Here if you want the output string with spaces you can join with space this will add space between words.